# what does stack and heap overflow exploit means

Tags: c++, tcp, stack, stack-overflow, heap-memory

what does this stack and heap over flow exploit mean

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged this with `tcp`?

Comment: stack-overflow means you're here, while heap-overflow means join me creating one : D

Comment: @Oded i was going through some TCP attacks and there i came across this...but cudn't able to find a good article on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of Stack-based exploitation: (implementation defined or possibly undefined, nevertheless interesting!)

Just look at the output:
http://www.ideone.com/A3vlY

Also note the runtime-error!

I'm particularly trying to do this:

> - By overwriting the return address in a stack frame. Once the function
>     returns, execution will resume at the
>     return address as specified by the
>     attacker, usually a user input filled
>     buffer.

From wikipedia's Stack-based exploitation [bullet points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Stack-based_exploitation)

This example possibly demonstrates the above bullet-point quoted from wikipedia, giving you an interesting starting point of what Stack-based exploitation could mean. Sort of impetus for thought!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a pretty good overview of these types of exploits: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Answer (score 0):

For a real world example of this, check out this other Stack Overflow question:

[Writing to pointer out of bounds after malloc() not causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534780/writing-to-pointer-out-of-bounds-after-malloc-not-causing-error)