# I want to understand malloc() and realloc() in C

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing to pointer out of bounds after malloc() not causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534780/writing-to-pointer-out-of-bounds-after-malloc-not-causing-error)

I am trying a very basic program to allocate memory for an array of only 2 `ints`. I am allocating memory for only 2 `ints`, that is, `array[0]`, and `array[1]`: why is it possible to use `array[2]` and its working well?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *array;
    int i;
    array = NULL;
    array = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);

    array[0] = 2;
    array[1] = 3;
    array[2] = 4;

    for( i = 0; i<3 ; i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
 2
 3
 4
```

Answer (score 3):

This may *appear* to work, because C doesn't prevent you from accessing memory that doesn't belong to you. Even if it appears to be working, the code is still incorrect, and may not work tomorrow. You're invoking undefined behavior by writing/reading memory that doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score 3):

Read answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534780/writing-to-pointer-out-of-bounds-after-malloc-not-causing-error) for a better understanding

It's in essence memory corruption as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534790/1013444)

Try using a very large number instead of 4 and it will produce the error because When you call malloc() a small chunk of memory is carved out of a larger page for you. So writing beyond the bounds of your chunk doesn't necessarily mean you are going to crash. At array[4] you are not writing outside the bounds of the page allocated for that initial chunk so you are technically writing to a valid mapped address. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4539567/1013444)

Answer (score 2):

pb2q is absolutely correct. One way to possibly verify that you are accessing un-allocated memory would be to do the following:

```
array = calloc(sizeof(int) * 2); 
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

You will probably receive the following output:

```
0
0
*random value*
```

Comment: Is there any function for which I could put my 'signal value' to fill the memory chunk?

Answer (score 0):

Because C doesn't try to hold your hand. You can read/write to unallocated memory, but you could very well be modify/pulling data from other objects, or just pulling garbage data.

When you create an array, you get a pointer to an address in memory, and can use that however you'd like. By allocating memory, you prevent other objects from being created within that chunk of memory, as if you'd reserved it for your array. However, there is no restriction on going past that amount, and you can read and write to wherever you'd like. The upside to this is that you have quite a bit of power and can manipulate addresses directly. The downside is that you can very easily cause your program to fall apart my manipulating information at memory locations belonging to other objects.

The thing to take away from this is that C gives you great amounts of power, and leaves the usage of that power wholly up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it works because your implementation of `malloc`  puts some information before and after the block of memory and maybe allocates in blocks (i.e. rounds the allocation request to the nearest 64 bytes, for example). `malloc`ed memory has to be able to be freed, and this requires some information about its size and so on, this information is put just before and/or after the allocated memory.

If the data is allocated in chunks, then there will be some limit you can reach where you've entirely filled one "block" and the read of `array[n]` will be off the end of the "block". We can test this as follows:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char * a;
    for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        a = malloc(i);
        a[i] = 'x';
        printf("%d %c\n", i, a[i]);
        free(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It `malloc`s increasingly larger blocks of memory and checks for out-of-bounds segfaults. The truncated output I get is:

```
1 x
[...]
58 x
59 x
60 x
61 x
62 x
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0a041008 ***
[...]
```

I.e. trying to do `a = malloc(63); a[63] = 'x';` fails, because it corrupts the metadata I was talking about before.

Answer (score 0):

here's the tip: you have to avoid the use of the printf on functions... use it only inside the  main() (:

when you use malloc and realloc, C will allocate memory with the size of a int. It will not allocate another "place" to put a number. The only thing that happens is if the data that you put has the same byte size of a int. That's something that usually happens, because C won't tell you if the array size is full. Be careful with that.