# Linux malloc segmentation fault missing

Tags: linux, kernel, memory-management

The included program should produce a segmentation fault in Linux, but it doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* This program should produce a segmentation error */
/* but it doesn't */

/* Therefore memory bounds are not being checked by the kernel */

typedef struct {
   double x;
} blkfmt;

int main()
{
   blkfmt *blk;
   unsigned char *p;
   blk = (blkfmt *) malloc(sizeof(blkfmt));
   p = (unsigned char *) blk + 16384;
   /* this assignment should produce a segmentation error */
   *p = (unsigned char) 0xff;
   /* this print statement should produce a segmentation error */
   printf("%02x %d\n", *p, sizeof(blkfmt));
   free(blk);
   return(0);
} /* main */
```

### makefile:

```make
OBJ=bug.o    
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS=

bug:                $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -Wall -O2 $(OBJ) -o bug $(LDFLAGS)

bug.o:              bug.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) bug.c

clean:
        rm -f bug $(OBJ)
```

Comment: It will write outside the intended struct, but probably not the stack.  Why do you expect a seg fault?

Comment: That is the thing about undefined behavior. Since memory allocators only need to follow a few rules, they can do almost anything else imaginable. In this case your malloc is likely allocating a much larger memory area, and so you are able to write into it. But you can't count on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to pointer out of bounds after malloc() not causing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534780/writing-to-pointer-out-of-bounds-after-malloc-not-causing-error)

Answer (score 2):

A memory allocator can do almost anything it wants to. Which is why this isn't acting as you expect.

The following is the output of `strace` running your program. In it you can see the `brk` system call is used to allocate 0x21000 more bytes for the program. That's 135,168 bytes. Much more than the 16,384 your program adds to the returned pointer.

```
execve("./malloc-outside-test", ["./malloc-outside-test"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1211000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2efad76000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183184, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 183184, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2efad49000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\10\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2089496, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3938656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2efa792000
mprotect(0x7f2efa94b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2efab4a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b8000) = 0x7f2efab4a000
mmap(0x7f2efab50000, 14688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2efab50000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2efad48000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2efad47000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2efad46000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2efad47700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2efab4a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f2efad77000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f2efad49000, 183184)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1211000
brk(0x1232000)                          = 0x1232000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1232000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "ff 8\n", 5)                   = 5
exit_group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour is undefined - there's no requirement to detect an report the error.  Most implementations favour performance over error detection.

If you want to check your program for correctness (hint: you do, just like the rest of us!), then you'll want to use Valgrind.  When I run Valgrind with your program, it reports both your errors:

```
==26331== Invalid write of size 1
==26331==    at 0x40059E: main (38255191.c:21)
==26331==  Address 0x51de040 is 16,304 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,128 in arena "client"
==26331== 
==26331== Invalid read of size 1
==26331==    at 0x4005A5: main (38255191.c:23)
==26331==  Address 0x51de040 is 16,304 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,128 in arena "client"
==26331==
```

---

In passing, I noticed a couple of problems in your code.  `sizeof blkfmt` is a `size_t`, so you need the `%zd` conversion.

Also, one should never cast the result of `malloc`, as this can mask other problems.  A good idiom is `p = malloc(sizeof *p)` - this is obviously correct without having to even look up the type of `p`.

Also, you didn't need to include `<unistd.h>`.

Simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double *blk = malloc(sizeof *blk);;
    unsigned char *p = malloc(sizeof *blk);
    p = (unsigned char*)blk + 16384;
    /* this assignment writes to unallocated memory */
    *p = 0xff;
    /* this reads from unallocated memory */
    printf("%02x %zd\n", *p, sizeof *blk);
    free(blk);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

malloc will get bigger space from kernel by page(4096), so if the pointer point to a valid space, it will not crash.