# Malloc don't segmentation fault

Tags: malloc

I have this code:

```
char *test = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
test[0] = 't';
test[1] = 'e';
test[2] = 's';
test[3] = 't';
test[4] = '\0';
printf("%s", test);
```

I malloc my test with one sizeof char.
But when I run this program, my program don't segfault. Why ? ..

Thanks you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to pointer out of bounds after malloc() not causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534780/writing-to-pointer-out-of-bounds-after-malloc-not-causing-error)

Answer (score 0):

In brief, malloc is not guaranteed to catch all memory misbehaviors of your program and throw a segmentation fault.

In fact, people would argue that this is just the best case scenario, where in the worst case you will be overwriting other data of your program.

See duplicate post for more detail.